# Создать класс по обработке массива данных

Tags: c++, ооп, vector

ООП в плюсах для меня тема новая. Нужно написать класс my_sample который должен иметь среди своих приватных полей вектор long double, который назвать vi. Он должен иметь конструктор по умолчанию.
Добавьте конструктор, который принимает вектор long double в качестве аргумента и использует его для инициализации объекта. Добавьте функцию print, которая записывает my_sample в выходной поток, передаваемый в качестве параметра. Выходной формат должен быть: *’<’ integer ’:’ space num1 space ... numN space ’>’,*, где integer - кол-во элементов вектора.
Перегрузите оператор <<, чтобы он записывал в выходной поток, переданный в качестве параметра, используя для этого функцию print my_sample.

Добавить следующие функции:

get_data (): возвращает вектор данных объекта my_sample.
minimum() - минимальное число в массиве
maximum() - максимальное число в массиве

Перегрузить оператор >>, чтобы мы могли прочитать my_sample из потока.
Формат ввода должен точно соответствовать формату вывода.

Comment: va = vi; надо :vi(va)

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков Можно немного подробнее, для чего это?

Comment: Где my_sample()=default; ? Где #include <vector> ?  Где ; у my_sample a ={12.4, 14.5, 155.8} ? Код надо бы исправить чтобы он хотя бы компилился...

Comment: Ответы на вопрос для чего лучше расскажет google.com а так надобы копировать в переменную vi а не в va.

Comment: Вы бы не могли показать пример в коде? ООП плюсов для меня слишком далеко. Пример реализации я бы тоже был крайне рад увидеть.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_ru&newwindow=1&biw=1430&bih=1042&tbs=lr%3Alang_1ru&ei=3BrgXcaAEsKxrgTknY-IBw&q=c%2B%2B+%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81&oq=c%2B%2B+%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67j0i7i30l3j0j0i7i30j0i67j0i7i30j0j0i7i30.2726.2726..2950...0.1..0.75.75.1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.OiSlH1ALqi0&ved=0ahUKEwjG3u-OzY3mAhXCmIsKHeTOA3EQ4dUDCAs&uact=5 вот что выдаёт гугл, неужели там нет кода?

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков я бы не стал писать вопрос, если бы нашел явный пример кода кода, который удовлетворяет мои нужды. И был бы крайне благодарен, если бы вы показали как решить данную проблему в ответе.

Comment: Сначала следует исправить синтаксические ошибки потом уже говорить что не так. Текущий код не работоспособен полностью.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков Исправил

Comment: Серавно не компилится ошибка в строке my_sample a = { 12.4, 14.5, 155.8 };

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков Именно, ибо я не знаю как создать реализацию данного вектора. В этом и есть проблема. За этим я и обратился

Comment: my_sample a ({12.4, 14.5, 155.8}); ?

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков my_sample.cc:11:17: warning: defaulted function definitions are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    my_sample()=default;
                ^
my_sample.cc:13:5: error: constructor cannot be redeclared
    my_sample(vector<long double> va)
    ^
my_sample.cc:12:5: note: previous declaration is here
    my_sample(vector<long double> vi);
    ^
my_sample.cc:34:18: error: expected expression
    my_sample a ({12.4, 14.5, 155.8});
                 ^
1 warning and 2 errors generated.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков error: expected expression

Comment: компилятор способен выдавать только 1 ошибку нормально - первую. остальное как получится

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков При такой компиляции g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++11 -o my_sample my_sample.cc - все компилится, но результат <0>

Comment: Очевидно что результат 0 ведь в vi никогда ничего не записывается. Компилить из командной строки плохая идея вообще.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков а где мне присваивать значение тогда, чтобы реализация в main работала?

Comment: хотябы где нибудь

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков Вы можете подсказать конкретнее? В определениях конструктора?

Comment: Если я пытаюсь декларировать его в конструкторе так my_sample()
    {
        vi = {};
    }, то ругается на default выше. Что невозможно редекларировать класс. Если убираю дефолт, компилится, но результат - 0.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков я изменил код, теперь все работает, но как теперь сделать это "Перегрузите оператор <<, чтобы он записывал в выходной поток, переданный в качестве параметра, используя для этого функцию print my_sample."

Comment: my_sample() = default; и  my_sample()[vi = {};} это два определения одного и того же конструктора. Так делать нельзя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

добавил вывод, ввод примерные, точную спецификацию вашего класса не понимаю

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "my_sample.h"

using namespace std;


class my_sample
{
private:
  vector<long double> vi;

public:
  //my_sample() = default;
  my_sample()
  {
    vi = {};
  }
  my_sample(vector<long double> _vi)
  {
    vi = _vi;
  }
  friend void print(ostream& out, const my_sample &obj)
  {
    out << '<';
    out << obj.vi.size();
    out << ':';
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.vi.size(); i++)
    {
      out << obj.vi[i] << ' ';
    }
    out << '>';
  }


  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const my_sample &obj) {
      print(out, obj);
      return out;
  }
  friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, my_sample &obj) {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n;++i) {
      int x;
      cin >> x;
      obj.vi.push_back(x);
    }
    return in;
  }

};

int main()
{
  my_sample a({ 12.4, 14.5, 155.8 });
  print(cout, a);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, я обновил код в шапке. Только правильный я указал ввод? Если на вход идет массив?

Comment: И если покажите пример как юзать in - буду крайне благодарен.

Comment: @HoneyCake добавил ввод, но им можно пользоваться постоянно то есть будут добавляться элементы навверх вектора, логично было бы в конструктор уже размер закидывать, и перезаписывать с помощью этого опрератора элементы

Comment: получается: мало того, что конструктор не может принять константный вектор, но еще и копирует этот вектор, еще и вызывает оператор присваивания, когда мог вызвать только конструктор  копирования.  Если обьект конструируется от вектора, то класс вполне мог содержать не  сам вектор, а  указатель(лучше умный) на него... И с чего это print сделать другом, а не членом?...

Comment: в задании  есть требование: добавлять метод  get_data (). Если его добавить, тогда  операторы ввода и вывода можно определять вне класса, и не  нужны никакие друзья... p.s.  my_sample() = default; вполне достаточное определение. B операторе вывода стоило проверять состояние потокового обьекта ...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan да тут все лучше переделать вообще согласен, я добавил только 2 перегрузки как friend на скорую руку, как автор попросил